# List<JAXBElement> in adapter code impacting JSON format

Tags: json, xml, jaxb

I would like to format the json output to contain only string for objects having only one element and not array. Below is my POJO.

```
  @Component("myVO")
@Scope("prototype")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "sectionList"})
public class MyVO extends ServiceResponseTO {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9190950749517871535L;

@XmlElement(name="ABC")
private String a;

@XmlElement(name="DEF")
private String b;

@XmlElement(name="GHI")
private String c;

@XmlElement(name="JKL")
private String d;

@XmlElement(name="MNO")
private String e;

@XmlElement(name="PQR")
private String f;

@XmlElement(name="section")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
private List<Map<String, String>> sectionList ;

    //corresponding getters and setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DetailsVO [a=" + a + ", b=" + b
            + ", c=" + c + ", d=" + d
            + ", e=" + e + ", f=" + f
            + ", sectionList=" + sectionList+ "]";
}


}
```

The issue is with my adapter code below.

```
    class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<KeyValuesAsNodeList, Map<String, String>> {
      public KeyValuesAsNodeList marshal(Map<String,String> map) throws Exception {
        KeyValuesAsNodeList mapType = new KeyValuesAsNodeList();
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){
                if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("key1")
                    mapType.key1 = entry.getValue().toString();

                if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("key2")
                    mapType.key2 = entry.getValue().toString();

                if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("key3")
                    mapType.key3 = entry.getValue().toString();

                if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("key3")
                    mapType.key3 = entry.getValue().toString();

                if( entry.getValue().getClass().equals(HashMap.class) || entry.getValue().getClass().equals(LinkedHashMap.class)){
                    mapType.entries.add(new JAXBElement(new QName(entry.getKey(),String,class,marshal(entry.getValue()))));
                }
                else{   
                    // For the issue I mentioned.. The value is a string.. so it enters this part. Here the problem lies
                    mapType.entries.add(new JAXBElement(new QName(entry.getKey(),String,class,entry.getValue())));
                }

            }   
        }
}

       public Map<String, String> unmarshal(Map<String, String> ) throws Exception {
           return null;
      }
}



class KeyValuesAsNodeList
{
  @XmlAttribute
   public String key1 ;

  @XmlAttribute
  public Integer key2;

   @XmlAttribute
   public String  key3;

   @XmlAttribute
   public String key4;
    //since I have given JAXBElement as a list, even my strings are retured as an array in JSON. 
    List<JAXBElement> entries = new ArrayList<JAXBElement>();
}
```

Using my above adapter, if I try to convert to JSON, the response is formed as below.

```
{"returnCode":"00","response":{"type":"myVO","ABC":"A","DEF":"B","GHI":"C","JKL":"D","MNO":"E","PQR":"F","section":[{"name":"SectionOne","configuration":"OOO","NAME":["N"],"SECTIONNAME":["A"]}]}}
```

The above response contains JSON array even for a single element. I want the above output to be formed like below.

The response I need is:

```
{"returnCode":"00","response":{"type":"myVO","ABC":"A","DEF":"B","GHI":"C","JKL":"D","MNO":"E","PQR":"F","section":[{"name":"SectionOne","configuration":"OOO","NAME":"N","SECTIONNAME":"A"}]}}
```

I dont want array for NAME and SECTIONNAME.  I would like to change the adapter in such a way that I get the desired JSON output and also that doesnot affect my XML

P.S: With this, adapter, my XML response is perfect.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Eclipse Moxy solved the issue. My requirement was to have the HashMap keys as XML nodes. Using @XmlVariableNode instead of List did the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Change data type of sectionList field to:

```
private Map<String, String> sectionList ;
```

Comment: My requirement is to have a List of maps. I have many sections, each section as a Map and the sectionList containg all the maps. Is there a solution to the problem with this requirement?